# PHP - Why floor() give me another result of sams calculation

Tags: php, calculation, floor

```
 for($i=0;$i<=15120;$i+=504){
      echo ($i/60/8.4) . " - " .floor($i/60/8.4)."<br>";
 }
```

Result (i make ** at problem) :

0 - 0

1 - 1

2 - 2

3 - 3

4 - 4

5 - 5

6 - 6

**7 - 6**

8 - 8

**9 - 8**

10 - 10

11 - 11

12 - 12

13 - 13

**14 - 13**

15 - 15

16 - 16

17 - 17

**18 - 17**

etc...

At start i think i apply "Floo" at all calculation but (for line "7-6") also $i = 3528 :

```
3528 / 60 = 58,8 == Floor ==> 58 / 8 = 7.25
```

floor of 7.25 =/= 6

Comment: `3528 / 60 / 8.4` gives in fact `6.999999999999999999999` could be displayed as `7` but `floor(6.9999999999999999999999) == 6`

Comment: But i've try on my Iphone or Google Calc and i get 7. 

And if i make 7 x 6.4 x 60 => 3528 

If you're that division give 6.9~ i take it at solution ^^

Comment: Ho i've find somhting. You have right ! Floating point

Comment: number_format (($i/60/8.4), 100) give 6.99~ result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it because of PHPs [floating point precision](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

so your 8th calculation for example will not return 7, but something like 6.9999999999999999999999999999

as this is a double, it will be rounded to 7 on output, try this out:

```
$x = 6.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
echo $x;
```

when you use `floor()` it will (correctly) round it down to 6